# State machine in C using Plecs

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement, state-machine

Hello I've been programming a State Machine in a C-script in Plecs and I'd Had the issue that at the time I compile it, it says that there is an error in all the lines that I used an if statement saying "expected expression". 
I tried using sublime text to be sure that I put right all the brackets and used sublimeLintern to review if I had some syntax errors.

```
//Maquina de estados
  switch(Charger_State_Machine){

   case INIT:
//Inicio de operación 
    if(start_carga==1){
     Charger_State_Machine = CON_CAR;
    }
    if(start_carga==0){ 
     Charger_State_Machine=CC_BOOST;
    }
    break;

    case CON_CAR:
//Auto conectado
    if(start_carga==0){
        Charger_State_Machine=TRANS;
        }   
    if(Charger_voltage>= trigger_voltage){
    Charger_State_Machine= CC_FAST;
    }
    else{
    Charger_State_Machine=CC_SLOW;
    }
break;
//Corriente constante en carga rapida
case CC_FAST:
    if(start_carga==0){
        Charger_State_Machine=TRANS;
    }   

    if(EV_VOLT>=EV_VOLT_TRIGGER){
        Charger_State_Machine=CV_FAST;
    }
//Tensión constante en carga rápida 
break;  
case CV_FAST:

    if(start_carga==0){
        Charger_State_Machine=TRANS;
    }

    if(EV_CUR<EV_CUR_TRIGGER){
        Charger_State_Machine=REG;
    }

break;
//Corriente constate en carga lenta
case CC_SLOW:

    if(start_carga==0){
        Charger_State_Machine=TRANS;
    }
    if(EV_VOLT>=EV_VOLT_TRIGGER){
        Charger_State_Machine=CV_SLOW;
    }

break;
//Tensión constante en carga lenta
case CV_SLOW_SLOW:
    if(start_carga==0){
        Charger_State_Machine=TRANS;
    }
    if(EV_CUR<=EV_CUR_TRIGGER){
        Charger_State_Machine=CC_BOOST;
    }

break;
//Estado transitorio
case TRANS:
if(start_carga==1){
    Charger_State_Machine=CON_CAR;
}
if(start_carga==0){
    Charger_State_Machine=CC_BOOST;
}
break;
//Corriente constante modo Boost
case CC_BOOST:
if(start_carga==1){
    Charger_State_Machine=CON_CAR;
}
if(CHARGER_VOLT>=CHARGER_VOLT_TRIGGER){
    Charger_State_Machine=CV_BOOST;
}

break;
//Tensión constante modo Boost
case CV_BOOST_BOOST:
if(start_carga==1){
    Charger_State_Machine=CON_CAR;
}
if(CHARGER_CUR<=CHARGER_CUR_TRIGGER){
    Charger_State_Machine=INIT;
}

break;
//En caso de que todo falle vuelvo al estado inicial
default:
    Charger_State_Machine=INIT;
    break;
 }
```

Code declarations

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
  //Definicion de estados
 enum   States {INIT,REG,CON_CAR,CV_FAST,CC_FAST,CC_SLOW,CV_SLOW,CC_BOOST,CV_BOOST,TRANS};
 enum States Charger_State_Machine = INIT;
  //Definicion de entradas
  #define EV_CUR          = Input(0)
  #define EV_VOLT         = Input(1)
  #define CHARGER_CUR     = Input(2)
  #define CHARGER_VOLT    = Input(3)
  #define CHARGER_VOLTAGE = Input(4)
  #define start_carga     = Input(5)
  //Definicion de salidas
  #define slow  = Output(0)
  #define end   = Output(1)
  #define dabcc = Output(2)
  #define isbcc = Output(3)
  #define isbcc_boost = Output(4)
  #define dab_boost = Output(5)
  #define zero = Output(6)
  //Definicion de constantes
  double TRIGGER_VOLTAGE=50;
  double EV_CUR_TRIGGER=0.01;
  double EV_VOLT_TRIGGER=38;
  double CHARGER_VOLT_TRIGGER=110;
  double CHARGER_CUR_TRIGGER=0.01;
```

Comment: Thanks, I just included it

Comment: What's with all those equal signs in your `#define`s? No wonder you're getting errors.

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: the posted code is missing any function definitions, like `main()`

Comment: what are the functions: `Input()` and `Output()`?

Comment: OT: regarding: `double TRIGGER_VOLTAGE=50;` and similar statements.  This is trying to force a `int` value into a `double` variable.  Strongly suggest: `double TRIGGER_VOLTAGE=50.0;` so initializing a `double` variable with a `double` literal

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include <math.h>` and `#include <float.h>`  it is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not being used.

Comment: regarding statements like: `#define EV_CUR          = Input(0)`  cannot perform assignments like this.  Suggest: `#define EV_CUR Input(0)`  which means the call to `Input()` with a parameter of 0 will be executed in statements like: `if(EV_CUR<EV_CUR_TRIGGER)`

Answer (score 1):

make sure that switch case is used with only variables of data type int or char